# unable to parse XML in pig

Tags: data-cleaning, apache-hadoop, apache-pig

I have a XML file has this structure (not exactly a tree though)

```
<posthistory>
<row Id="1" PostHistoryTypeId="2" PostId="1" 
RevisionGUID="689cb04a-8d2a-4fcb-b125-bce8b7012b88" 
CreationDate="2015-01-27T20:09:32.720" UserId="4" Text="I just got a 
pound of microroasted, local coffee and am curious what the optimal 
way to store it is (what temperature, humidity, etc)" />
```

I am using apache pig to extract just the "Text" part using this code

```
grunt> A = load 'hdfs:///parsingdemo/PostHistory.xml' using 
org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('posthistory') as(x:chararray);

grunt> result = foreach A generate XPath(x, 'posthistory/Text');
```

this returns "()" (null)

Upon examining the XML file, I learnt that my XML file should be in this format:

```
<root>
  <child>
    <subchild>.....</subchild>
  </child>
</root>
```

But my XML data file (stackoverflow data dump actually) is not in this format. Is there a way the tree structure can be imposed? what is wrong with my pig query?

Answer (score 1):

This XPath will look for a *tag* called `<Text>` inside a tag called `<posthistory>`:

```
XPath(x, 'posthistory/Text');
```

You want to find the `Text` attribute of the `row` tag in `posthistory` tags.

An XPath something like this will do that: `/posthistory/row/@Text`

See example here: http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/bac9874ec344f9d8ebcfb250633aaf65 and click "Test" to see results set.

Learn up on XPath notation for more.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression.Following is a generic format

```
 foreach A GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(x,'<child>\\s*<subchild1>(.*)</subchild1>\\s*<subchild2>(.*)</subchild2>\\s*</child>'));
```